# Communicating with raspberry pi over internet

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am a newbie to networking.

I have a Rpi-A connected to internet via 3G surf-stick and Rpi-B connected to internet via a WiFi hotspot.

I noticed that Rpi-A has a public IP address and Rpi-B has local/private IP. Both raspberry Pi's are on different networks.

I want to send binary data from Rpi-A to Rpi-B. Any suggestions on how can this be achieved?

update:
I used the below code to test the MQTT connection.
replacing XX.XX.XX.XX with public IP of raspberry Pi. Still I end up getting this error---> error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
what might be the possible reason for this error ? Is there anything missing in my code

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect

client.connect("xx.xx.xxx.x", 1883, 60)

client.loop_start()

while True:
  time.sleep(2)
  client.publish('Due_0.72/cmd/in','hello')
  print "publish.."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your running RPi B on a hotspot that is not controlled by you. You would either create a reverse connection from Pi B to Pi A (something like ncat should work) and send data accross that way or use something like a OpenVPN server in the cloud and route between the 2 Pi.

If you have access to the Wi-Fi hotspot configuration port forward something like ssh to Pi B. (General port 22/tcp if using the standard configuration)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @ITAIfs. I have access to Wi-Fi router so I can do port forwarding. I guess I need to open port 1883 since I want to use MQTT.

Answer (score 0):

On the RPi-B's network there must be a router that is using NAT to let RPI-B connect to internet through a public address.

Like this:

[image]

You have to get into the configuration of that router and open an specific port (for example 22) and forward all the incoming traffic to that port to the RPi-B's IP address.

RPi-B will be accesible to the public internet through the combination of RPI-B's **public** IP address and port 22.

Now, from RPi-A you can use *SFTP* to send data to RPi-B.

Comment: Okay I will definitely try this and post the result. Any idea how can this be done using MQTT ?

Comment: @Spark    Yes. The port for MQTT is 1883, and port 8883 is  MQTT over SSL.